# Google Maps Embed API rendering issues with .net web browser control

Tags: .net, winforms, google-maps

Until a few weeks ago, I was able to render a Google Maps request in a .net webBrowser control in a winForms application. Now, suddenly the Google Map is rendering incorrectly. Does anyone have any insight? Here's some vb snippets...

```
    Dim url As String = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&ie=UTF8&output=embed&z=15&q=100+Corporate+Woods,+Rochester,+NY+14623,+USA"
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    sb.Append("<html>")
    sb.Append("<head>")
    sb.Append("</head")
    sb.Append("<body>")

    sb.Append("<iframe src =""" & url & """ height=""" & 800 & """ width=""" & 800 & """ frameborder=""0"" style=""border:0""></iframe>")

    sb.Append("</body")
    sb.Append("</html>")

    WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = False
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = sb.ToString
```

And now the output looks like this:

[image]

Does any have any insight or workarounds?

Comment: Did Google not just release a fairly substantive upgrade (upheaval?) of the Google Maps service/API very recently?

Comment: They sure did, hence the problem.

Comment: Wondering if what they are outputting is now HTML5 compliant, whereas the .net webBrowser control may not be...purely spitballing on this one...

Comment: That's a great guess and I'm sure it something along those lines (html/css/javascript), but I need to find a work around or a new map provider all together.... clients aren't happy!

Answer (score 1):

Google must have patched the issues, all is back to working as expected again.